# StreamWriter don't writing any text to file

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter

I wrote some code, which should write to file some text:

```
        private static FileStream CreateFile()
        {
            string _fileName = "znaki.txt";

            if(File.Exists(_fileName))
            {
                File.Delete(_fileName);
            }

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Ile znakok chcesz wygenerowac? >> ");
            int lp;
            lp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Random r = new Random();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            for (int i = 0; i < lp; i++)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(i + "/" + lp);

                sw.WriteLine("jogurcik");
            }

            return fs;
        }
```

This code create the file but don't write anything. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close StreamWriter (as well as FileStream) at the end of the writing routine:

```
sw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.close?view=netframework-4.8):

> You must call Close to ensure that all data is correctly written out
>   to the underlying stream... Flushing the stream will not flush its underlying encoder unless you explicitly call Flush or Close.

P.S.
Alternative way is to use the `using` statement that helps to close and dispose of IO objects automatically:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    ...
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs)) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < lp; i++)
        {
            ...
            sw.WriteLine("jogurcik");
        }
    }
}
```

In this case you can ommit the close call.

Comment: Added P.S. about the `using` statement that helps to close StreamWriter automatically.